# Javascript: converting binary data in Uint8Array to string corrupting file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, encoding, base64

I'm trying to upload a video file in chunks to a server via a standard jQuery `$.ajax` call. The process is simple:

1. Use the `slice()` method on the file object to read a chunk
2. Use `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer` to read the resulting blob
3. Create a `Uint8Array` of that result in the FileReader.onload callback
4. Use `String.fromCharCode.apply(null, intArrayName)` to convert it into a binary string
5. Upload that binary string as a chunk in the AJAX call's `data` property

When I finish uploading all the chunks, the server's API complains that the file upload is incomplete. To test this method, I converted the concatenated binary strings into a Blob and had Chrome save it to my downloads folder, only to find out my media player said the file was unplayable.

I've read posts on this site and [other articles](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/30/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx/) suggesting that directly converting binary data represented by integers to strings results in a loss of data, and that the suggestion is convert it to a base64-encoded string, since Javascript doesn't have a StreamContent object like C# does.

The problem is that even if I set `Content-Transfer-Encoding` to `base64` I don't think the API (which wasn't written by us) picks up on it and can tell that a base64 decoding is needed.

My question is: is this the only sure-fire way of sending video data over an AJAX call safely? If not, how else can I send it in the data field of my AJAX request? There are probably thousands of uploaders like this on the Internet but nowhere can I find solid documentation on how to do this. If it turns out that the server needs to expect base64 encoding, we might have to write a middle-man API to do this decoding for us.

Comment: Why are you converting the blob? Why not just directly add the sliced blob to the ajax call?

Comment: you can `xhr.send(elmForm)` or `xhr.send(blob)`, and you can use a `FormData()` if you want to mimic an old-school file upload.

Comment: @PatrickEvans thank you! That did it. I got the impression you had to convert it given the examples found on SO and elsewhere on the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Patrick Evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560593/patrick-evans), it turns out all I needed to do was upload the blob itself:

```
function upload(file) {
  var offset = 0; // what's been sent already
  var fileSize = file.size;
  var chunkSize = 64 * 1024; // bytes

  while (offset < fileSize) {
    var blob = file.slice(offset, chunkSize + offset);

    var urlToUse = ((offset + blob.size) >= fileSize) ? videoFinishBaseUrl : videoContinueBaseUrl;

    $.ajax({
      url: urlToUse,
      method: 'POST',
      data: blob,
      headers: requestHeaders,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        jQuery('#uploadmsg').text('Finished offset ' + offset);
        offset += blob.size;
      },
      error: function(err) {
        jQuery('#uploadmsg').text(err);
      }
    });

  }
};
```